# whole page gets refresh instead of div on login action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have 1 home page on which I have one anchor tag that is Login. On click, the Login anchor tag opens one pop up on the same home page like shown in the image below:

[image]
Now I want to perform the login action when the sign in button is clicked but only this pop up portion should get refresh and not the whole home page.

Currently, what is happening is my whole home page gets refreshed when the user enters the wrong `EmailId` or `Password`.

This is my View:

```
 <div id="loginBox">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
    {
        <fieldset id="body">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { name = "email", id = "email" })
            </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="password">Password</label>

            @Html.Password("Password", null, new { name = "password", id = "password" })
        </fieldset>
        <input onclick="Login()" type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in">
        <label for="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
            <i>Remember me</i>
        </label>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

This is my Login Javascript method to post my form and call controller method:

```
function Login() {
        alert("ok");
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.post("/Account/Login", { Email: email, Password: password },
                                     function (data) {
                                         if (data == true) {
                                             $("#LoginErrorMsg").hide();

                                         } else {
                                              $("#LoginErrorMsg").show();
                                         }
                                    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Login(string Email, string Password)
{
    //Logic for login action
    if(Emailid && Password is correct)
        return Json(true); 
    else 
        return Json(false);
}
```

But here the problem is my controller method is not calling and when it is calling the whole page gets refresh even if the password is incorrect.

So can anybody help me?

Comment: Because you 'button' is `<input type="submit" ...>` which does just that - in you case doing both the ajax call and a form submit. Change it to `<button type="button">` or cancel the default submit action in the script.

Comment: so just doing this will not refresh the whole page?

Comment: No it will not refresh, but you have some other issues as well. Instead of `return Json(false);` use `return Json(null);` and in the success function, change `if (data == true)` to `if (data)` and you should not hard code the url - instead use  `'@Url.Action("Login", "Account")'`

Comment: Just this changes will do the work???

Comment: Try it! And as I have noted in previous answers to your questions, use Unobtrusive Javascript.

Comment: yaa i have already used unobstrusive javascript.so for this functionality which i slated in my question how would you like to do this same thing?

Comment: You have not used unobtrusive javascript. Your html has `<input onclick="Login()" ....>`. Unobtrusive javascript would be `$('#login).click(function() { ...`

Comment: oh i got it.but apart from that any other thing you would like to suggest???\